# Highcharts - Xrange chart events issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts' x-range chart module to render a range of multiple values. I have a couple of issues in implementing it.

1. The `hover` and `select` states are not having any effect on the chart
2. The `legend` icon is not showing the color of the data

Code below:

```js
var myChart7 = Highcharts.chart('sample', {
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
  },
  title: null,
  xAxis: {
    opposite: true,
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value + "ms";
      },
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    categories: [],
    reversed: true
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      allowPointSelect: true,
      states: {
        hover: {
          color: '#a4edba'
        },
        select: {
          color: '#EFFFEF',
          borderColor: 'black',
          dashStyle: 'dot'
        }
      },
      pointWidth: 15,
      borderRadius: 10,
      dashStyle: 'Solid',
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'left',
  },
  series: [{
      color: '#C4D9FF',
      name: 'Sample 1',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        x2: 90,
        y: 0,
        response: '200',
        color: '#C4D9FF',
        borderColor: '#789CDF',
      }],
    },
    {
      color: '#FFD7C5',
      name: 'Sample 2',
      data: [{
        x: 5,
        x2: 70,
        y: 1,
        response: '200',
        color: '#FFD7C5',
        borderColor: '#F99B6F',
      }],

    }, {
      color: '#DCFFF5',
      name: 'Sample 3',
      data: [{
        x: 35,
        x2: 70,
        y: 2,
        response: '400',
        color: '#DCFFF5',
        borderColor: '#35C097',
      }],
    }
  ],
});
```

```html
<div id="sample">

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.4/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.4/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.4/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vzxmyp6f/)

I don't know if I'm implementing it in the right or wrong way. Please guide me. TIA.

I'm working on Chrome version 85 on mac. Haven't tested it on other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Those features hasn't been implemented in the version of the Highcharts which you are using. In the current version everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/trxjw4np/
2. In the x-range series type the legend item doesn't inherit the color from the series, but you can set it programmatically.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/trxjw4np/

```
events: {
    load() {
        let chart = this;
        
        chart.legend.allItems.forEach(item => {
            item.legendSymbol.css({
                fill: item.userOptions.color
            })
        })
    }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Having one more issue in the same graph, the first and third bars are not aligned correctly within the grid lines (not centered). Is there a way to solve this? TIA

Comment: @AllanJebaraj I am not sure where the problem is and on which demo are you talking about. Could you describe it more precisely?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/trxjw4np/ The series in the graph are not vertically aligned with the corresponding y axis labels. The first series (blue) is not vertically aligned with the label '0'

Comment: @AllanJebaraj notice that you have 3 different series, you need to disable `grouping` for them to render them same as points: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/snuLvxcq/